# Given recurrence $a_{n+1}=\frac13a_n+2$, find $L$ so that the sequence $a_n-L$ is geometric

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let the sequence $\{a_n\}$ be given by the recursive relation $\displaystyle :a_{n+1} =\frac{a_n}{3}+2$, with $a_0 = x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find $L\in\mathbb{R}$ so that the sequence $\{a_n-L\}$ would be geometric.

Comment: Have you tried finding a general term for $a_n$? Seems not difficult.

Comment: It is a first-order recurrence: $a_n=\frac{A}{3^n}+3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n = a_n -L$. Then $b_{n+1} = a_{n+1} - L = \dfrac{a_n}{3}+2 - L = \dfrac{b_n+L}{3}+2 - L = \dfrac{b_n}{3}+\dfrac{6-2L}{3}$. Therefore, $L=3$ works.

Comment: And only L=3 works.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1} =\frac{1}{3}a_n+2 = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{1}{3}a_{n-1}+2 \right)+2 = \frac{1}{3^2}a_{n-1}+ \frac{2}{3} +2 = \frac{1}{3^3}a_{n-2}+ \frac{2}{3^2} + \frac{2}{3}+2 = \cdots=\\
=\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}x+\frac{2}{3^n}+\cdots +\frac{2}{3} +2
=\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}x+2\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}
= \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}x +3-\frac{1}{3^{n}}$$
So subtracting $L=3$ gives geometrical progression.